# Why does Ruby let me call a String method without specifying the string?

Tags: ruby, syntax

While reading [Programming Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/trouble.html), I ran across this code snippet:

```
while gets
  num1, num2 = split /,/
end
```

While I intuitively understand what it does, I don't understand the syntax. 'split' is a method on the String class - in Ruby parlance, which string is the receiver of the 'split' message in the scenario above?

I can see in the docs that 'gets' assigns its result to the variable $_, so my guess is that it is implicitly using $_ as the receiver - but a whole bunch of Google searching has failed to confirm that guess. If that is the case, I'd love to know what general rule for methods called without an explicit receiver.

I did try the code in irb, with some diagnostic puts calls added, and I verified that the actual behavior is what you would expect - num1 and num2 get assigned values that were input separated by a comma.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ruby 1.8 has a method `Kernel#split([pattern [, limit]])` which is identical to `$_.split(pattern, limit)`, and `gets` sets the value of `$_`.

Answer (score 4):

You basically nailed it with your explanation (at least for 1.8.7, 1.9.3 gave me a `NoMethodError` for `main`), but IMHO that's horrible Ruby (or maybe someone switching over from Perl). If you rewrite it to something like this, it becomes a lot clearer:

```
while input = gets.chomp
  num1, num2 = input.split(/,/)
end
```

The general rule for method calls without a receiver is that they are sent to `self`, whatever that may be in the current context. In the top level it's the aforementioned `main`, the `$_` looping Perlism seems to be gone in 1.9.

Comment: `$_` still exists (and is used by `gets`) in Ruby 1.9, but the method `Kernel#split` is gone. It worked previously not because `split` was being called on `$_`, but because it was being called on `Kernel`.

Comment: Yes, I phrased that very badly.

Comment: @MichelleTilley: it is being called on `self`, which at that point is `main`, not `Kernel`. `main`'s class is `Object`, and `Object` inherits from `Kernel` (more precisely *mixes in* `Kernel`), but that does by no means mean that the method is being called on `Kernel`. (You *could* theoretically call it on `Kernel`, because `Kernel`'s class is `Module`, `Module` inherits from `Object`, which mixes in `Kernel` and thus `Kernel` is an instance of itself, but that is a terribly confusing way to word it.)